# What technology to use to send custom requests from GUI to python script?

Tags: python, database, gui

I want to build an web app which crawls/scrapes multiple websites based on user preference for different products and I already have the code for scraping working. Next I have to build a GUI which lets the user select what more exactly he wants to see info about (like select area/characteristics of product).
I found a great way to display the collected info is Dash (my scraping code is already in python, with selenium), however I lack a technology which connects the GUI for user filters, saving the data to a permanent database after which it's displayed with Dash (although I'll mostly be showing tables probably).
Is Flask or React a good idea to handle GUI for user filters + binding to a permanent database?

Answer (score 1):

[TkInter](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TkInter) is the standard GUI package for creating desktop applications.

If you want to be browser-based, a simple solution is to use HTML / AJAX / JSON to communicate with Python and handle database CRUD and everything else from there.

Answer (score 0):

Need your want to be usually a website desktop application, the right solution is to use Ajax /Javascript /JSON to intimation with python and manage database CRUD everything else from there.

Comment: I think the OP might want to know its more exact names.